# Using dask-jobqueue with SGECluster.adapt() and submitting tasks before any worker is active

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have setup an `SGECluster` scheduler with the correct settings and confirmed I can connect to both the dashboard and submit jobs to my sge queue. I would like to use the `adapt` method to scale the number of workers dependent upon the incoming task load. These tasks are generally not related so they can be run by individual workers in their own process.

I've noticed that the scheduler does not appear to register tasks (at least in the dashboard) until a worker is available. If that first worker takes some time to become available and I submit tasks to the scheduler, it will not know that it needs to scale and therefore the extra workers will end up at the back of the queue. Is it possible to prompt the scheduler to recognize that tasks have arrived before the first worker has connected to the scheduler, and to put in queue requests for workers appropriately?

I can get the workers to queue if I use `scale(n)` instead of adapt.

```
cluster = SGECluster(
    queue=queue_name,
    memory=maximum_memory,
    processes=worker_processes,  
    env_extra=env_list,
    scheduler_options=scheduler_options,
    log_directory=log_dir,
    job_name=name,
    walltime=walltime,
    resource_spec=f"{mem_spec}={maximum_memory}",
    job_extra=job_extra_list,
)

# if the first worker takes ages to begin running, then only one worker will be requested
# and tasks submitted in the interim do not adjust the scheduler behaviour
# cluster.adapt(minimum=1, maximum=20)

# queues up the requested workers straight away but doesn't adapt to load
cluster.scale(20)
```

Comment: Correction, I can see the tasks in the task graph with the status 'no-worker'. But that still doesn't prompt any reaction from the adapt process.

Comment: I use `minimum_jobs`/`maximum_jobs` instead - and see that my jobs are being created and deleted instantly. At this point - I don't know how ti make `adapt` to work. Maybe @mrocklin might point to what we are doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue with SLURMCluster. My tasks aren't transferred to new workers. I recommend reading https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1851 first and also https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/4446

Comment: Also of interest: https://github.com/dask/distributed/commit/d8d0d4e71023ac6c1507b443b90d7805e2bf7ad2